# Goji Berry plants have not grown much over 2 years!

Tags: growth, fruits, goji

My Goji Berry plants have only grown in the spring, when they have grown at all. I had some berries the first year, but not since. (Of course, they only fruit on new wood, but the plants are growing a few inches per year). The plants should be 6 foot tall and cascading over towards the ground, filling in that area.

I have done every possible thing I can think of, or that the nursery can think of. The selling nursery said any PH would be fine... However, the internet says slightly alkaline soil is needed. This is my ONLY IDEA re the problem... I do NOT know if this is accurate for my variety re PH needed.
Note - the nursery says these plants don't like much water or fertilizer.

If it is that I need to raise the PH from approximately 5.75 to 7.0+, how do i do this?? Can I spread like over the surface where they are planted? How can I get results this year? Thanks!

Comment: What’s “re PH”?

Comment: @dakab - it just means 'regarding the ph...needed' it doesn't need editing to make sense

Answer (score 2):

Unless your soil ph is extreme one way or the other, goji berry is very adaptable, so I doubt that's an issue; the nursery you bought from is correct in that regard. What might be an issue is whether you enriched the soil with lots of organic material such as composted animal manure or good garden compost prior to planting, and whether you have mulched with something similar on a regular basis (certainly annually) since. You also have not mentioned whether you applied a general, balanced fertilizer (something with an NPK of 7-7-7 is fine) in spring, but it's usual to do so.

The second issue might be irregular water supply, or occasional drought conditions - you say they've been in two years, and the first two years is quite critical for any new, permanent planting in terms of availability of water. If the plant goes short, it takes longer to establish and doesn't do so well, and may even die, because it needs time to create an extensive root system for itself before it can really start putting on growth;  that process can take up to two years, longer if water shortage is a frequent problem.

Since you haven't given any detail about precisely what you've tried when you say you've 'tried every possible thing you can think of', and it's impossible to gauge what your usual weather conditions are like because you've not given your location, it's difficult to say for sure what the problem actually is; hopefully, you may find the above information is pertinent to your situation. More general information on goji berry growing here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=581